# Passar parametros no .on do jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, pessoal. Estou tentando fazer uma função para excluir um nó de um xml, porém eu tenho um problema que é o seguinte: No javascript puro basta eu por

> onclick="funcao('')"

dentro da tag html pra ele passar o parametro vindo como echo do php. Porém eu estou com dificuldades em fazer algo parecido em jquery. Eu apenas substituí o php por

> $(this).attr("id")

por que está dentro de um each. Podem me ajudar?
Obs: Eu já testei criando a função dentro do ready do jquery e não funcionou.

**Edit:**

O xml que eu estou usando é este

```
<dados><usuarios><usuario id="1"><login>marcos</login><senha>15</senha></usuario></usuarios><gastos><gasto user="1" id="1"><descricao>bk</descricao><valor>20</valor></gasto><gasto user="1" id="2"><descricao>mcdonalds</descricao><valor>15</valor></gasto></gastos></dados>
```

Eu preciso exibir os gastos em uma tabela, daí meu jquery fica assim:

```
$(xml).find("gasto").each(function() {
    if($(this).attr("user") == user) {
        $("#tablex tr:last").after("<tr><td>"+$(this).find("descricao").text()+"</td><td>"+$(this).find("valor").text()+'</td><td><button onclick="apagarGasto('+$(this).attr("id")+')">X</button></td><td><button class="up">U</button></td></tr>');
    }
});
```

Dentro do onclick podem ver que eu estou tentando passar o atributo id do gasto. Porém, se eu colocar a função apagarGasto dentro do `$(documento).ready(function)` ele me exibe no console que a função é indefinida, ou seja, que não existe. Logo, eu pensei que o onclick normal do javascript puro não funciona quando se usa jquery, estou certo? Então, eu preciso de uma maneira que possa passar o parametro id do gasto para uma função dentro do jquery. Por favor se eu não fui claro o suficiente, me digam! Obrigado antecipadamente!

Comment: Queres remover o nó clicado, é isso? Junta o xml relativo ao problema para ficar mais claro.

Comment: Além do que o Sergio pediu, se tu puder colocar, por gentileza, o código js que tu tá executando inteiro, fica mais fácil de ajudarmos. (=

Comment: Não. Os ouvintes padrão de js funcionam em qualquer condição. Sua função: apagarGasto, deve estar dentro das tags script e fora do $(document).ready.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode declarar seu ouvinte com on e obter um atributo data com seu parâmetro, por exemplo:

Alterei seu button um pouco para passasr o atributo data e adicionar a classe:

```
$(xml).find("gasto").each(function() {
    if($(this).attr("user") == user) {
        $("#tablex tr:last").after("<tr><td>"+$(this).find("descricao").text()+"</td><td>"+$(this).find("valor").text()+'</td><td><button class='btn-click' data-id=' + $(this).attr("id")+'">X</button></td><td><button class="up">U</button></td></tr>');
    }
});
```

e seu ouvinte para o evento de click no button:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-click", function(){
    var id = $(this).data("id");
});
```

Só não entendi qndo havia o retorno de função indefinida no exemplo que citou.